# Correct SyncRoot Style for my API

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

In my application, I have a class whose methods I want to be visited by only one thread at a time. This class performs some operations with a device on a COM-port and I don't want one thread to write to the port while the other is writing etc.

To use this class (which is not maintained by me) I have a Service-class which instantiates the COM-using class and servers as an API-layer to the rest of my application. Although the COM-class isn't directly maintained by me, I can edit it. It's just that a colleague of mine created it and I only do bug fixing in it. There is a lot of low level bit manipulation in there that I don't want to touch.

How would I go about enforcing one-thread only access to the COM-class.

Option A (which I have currently implemented):

```
class Service
{
    private ComClass comClass;

    private readonly object syncRoot = new object();

    public void DoThisWithCom()
    {
       lock(syncRoot)
       {
         comClass.DoSomething();
       }
    }
}
```

Option B:

```
class Service
{
    private ComClass comClass;

    public void DoThisWithCom()
    {
       lock(comClass)
       {
         comClass.DoSomething();
       }
    }
}
```

Option C (which is possible because I can edit the code for the COM-class):

```
class Service
{
    private ComClass comClass;

    public void DoThisWithCom()
    {
       lock(comClass.SyncRoot)
       {
         comClass.DoSomething();
       }
    }
}
```

Perhaps it's better to put all of this on the COM-class side of things, because it should be impossible for multiple threads to ever use the methods in this class at the same time.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is never a good idea to lock on public objects, because you cannot control where else this object is (mis)used as lock object, possibly causing a deadlock in your component. This effectively eliminates option C.

If the `ComClass` instance is created in your `Service` class and never is (and never will be made) available to the outside it is safe to lock on your `comClass` member. So, if this is true, go for option B, otherwise just keep your current implementation.